# Keep certain links in standalone mode on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

I've found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1042026) that does prevents links from webpages to go outside the "standalone mode" on an iPhone, but I'd like to disable this functionality on certain links with classes.

Whenever a modal is present, this functionality breaks it and quick opens the modal and then redirects to the `href`.

The code:

```
    if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) {
      var noddy, remotes = false;
      document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        noddy = event.target;
        while(noddy.nodeName !== "A" && noddy.nodeName !== "HTML") {
              noddy = noddy.parentNode;
          }
        if('href' in noddy && noddy.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && (noddy.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1 || remotes)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          document.location.href = noddy.href;
        }
      }, false);
    }
```

How can I modify it to include that `a` with classes, such as `open, modal` shouldn't use the above functionality and just keep the modal open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) {
  var noddy, remotes = false;
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    noddy = event.target;
    var className = noddy.className;
    if(noddy.nodeName === "A" 
        && (className.indexOf('open') != -1 || className.indexOf('modal') != -1)){
         return;//Just return without doing anything
    }

    while(noddy.nodeName !== "A" && noddy.nodeName !== "HTML") {
          noddy = noddy.parentNode;
      }
    if('href' in noddy && noddy.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && (noddy.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1 || remotes)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.location.href = noddy.href;
    }
  }, false);
}
```

As a side note if you are using `jQuery` in your page or application then your code can be reduced very much by using jQuery built in apis.

Comment: It opens all links outside app. If I comment out the `if` for standalone and leave the rest I get this error: SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'